# Solving a fourth-order Fokker Planck equation in Mathematica with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to solve numerically with NDSolve the following partial differential equation

\begin{align}
 \partial_t W = -p \partial_x W + \lambda x \,\partial_p W + \gamma \partial_p\left[p W\right]  + D_1\partial^3_p \left[p W\right] + D_2\partial^2_p W + D_3 \partial^4_p. W\end{align}

where $\lambda, \gamma, D_1, D_2, D_3$ are positive constants and $W=W(x,p,t)$. The initial condition are `W[x, p, 0] == delt[x, p], DirichletCondition[p[x, y, t] == 0, True]`, where `delt[x_, p_] := PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{.0015, 0}, {0, .0015}}], {x,p}]`

However, I am facing a hard time computing high-order derivatives on Mathematica since `NDSolve` only calculates up to the second-order derivative. Is there any other way to implement it?

That is my code:

```
delt[x_, p_] := 
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{.0015, 0}, {0, .0015}}], {x,p}];

FP = -p*D[W[x, p, t], x] + x*D[W[x, p, t], x] + 
  D[(p*W[x, p, t]), p] + .5*ϵ^2*
  D[W[x, p, t], {p, 2}] + + .5*ϵ^3*
  D[p*W[x, p, t], {p, 3}] + .5*ϵ^4*D[W[x, p, t], {p, 4}] 

ϵ = .2;

molfem[measure_ : Automatic] := {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> measure}};

sol = NDSolveValue[{D[W[x, p, t], t] ==  FP, W[x, p, 0] == delt[x, p],
      DirichletCondition[W[x, p, t] == 0, True]}, 
    W, {t, 0, 1}, {p, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}, 
    Method -> molfem[0.01]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

where now $\lambda = \gamma =1$, $D_1 = 0.5\epsilon^2$, $D_2 = 0.5\epsilon^3$, and $D_3 = 0.5\epsilon^4$. The error msg that I got is:

```
NDSolveValue::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.
```

Comment: It is helpful to those who would help to supply code instead of (or in addition to) LaTeX.  That reduces the barrier to helping considerably.

Comment: There is also a reference to Fokker Plank in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MassTransportPDEComponent.html#1981924737  Also, NDSolve does work for derivatives with order higher than 2: `sol = NDSolveValue[{z''''[x] == z[x], z[0] == 1, z'[0] == 0, 
   z'''[0] == 1, z[1] == 0}, z, {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: For numerical solution we need some range for `p, x, t` and numerical parameters $\gamma, \lambda, D_i$.

Comment: Sorry guys. Let me update the question by adding my code there. Now, I think it's better :).

Comment: I cold not verify your input to be the same as W[x, p, t] + p*Derivative[0, 1, 0][W][x, p, t] + 
  0.5*\[Epsilon]^2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][W][x, p, t] + 
  0.5*\[Epsilon]^3*(3*Derivative[0, 2, 0][W][x, p, t] + 
    p*Derivative[0, 3, 0][W][x, p, t]) + 
  0.5*\[Epsilon]^4*Derivative[0, 4, 0][W][x, p, t] - 
  p*Derivative[1, 0, 0][W][x, p, t] + 
  x*Derivative[1, 0, 0][W][x, p, t]

There is a ++0.5 somwhere

The fourth order equation has to be split into a system for {w,u} eg by D[w,x,x] =u